# Elasticsearch - is there an option or Flag to prevent indexes been searched using quires

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am doing an performance test for the querying using Esrally tool. But due to it's limitations ,
, when gave “index”: “_all”, it executes search queries on all the indices instead of search only the defined indices.

So there by, is there an option or Flag to prevent indexes been searched using quires ? I want to prevent highlighted indices from searching.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `index.hidden: true` option. it is static option, so you should close the indices first:

```
curl -s -XPOST "127.0.0.1:9200/elastalert/_close"
```

then

```
curl -s -XPUT "127.0.0.1:9200/elastalert/_settings?pretty" -d '
{ 
"index.hidden": true
}'
```

after that:

```
curl -s -XPOST "127.0.0.1:9200/elastalert/_open"
```

Comment: Thank you , let me give it a try and accept this.